# Prove that: $x^x\ge x,\;\forall x>0.$ (without taking logarithms)

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

My approach:

Let $f(x)=x^x-x.$ Then $f'(x)=x^x(1+\ln x)-1$ and $f''(x)=x^{x-1}+x^x(1+\ln x)^2>0,\;\forall x>0.$ That means $f'(x)$ is an increasing(strictly) function for all $x>0.$ So $\color{red}{x>1}\Rightarrow f'(x)>f'(1)\Rightarrow x^x(1+\ln x) -1>0.$ This implies $f(x)$ is an increasing(strictly) function for all $x>1.$ Therefore $x>1\Rightarrow f(x)>f(1)\Rightarrow x^x-x>0.$

$\boxed{\therefore x^x>x,\,\forall x>1.}\tag*{}$

But how to show that $x^x>x,\, \forall x\in(0, 1)$ ? And obviously $x^x=x$ at $x=1.$

What is wrong with my approach? Please suggest.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just as an addition to the better answers below, if you want to do it using derivatives, see what happens to $f'(x) \in (0,1]$. This requires finding the limit of $x^x$ as $x \to 0^+$. I think you will find that $f'(x)$ lies between $-\infty$ and $0$. So $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing in $(0,1)$. Hence, $f(1)<f(x) < f(0)$, which serves your purpose, because $lim_{x \to 0^+}(x^x-x) = 1$ and $f(1) = 0$.

Comment: Yes! Got it thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This can be solved without taking derivatives if you know that the logarithm is a strictly increasing function. We have (for all $x > 0$)
$$ 
 x^x \ge x \iff x \ln x \ge \ln x \iff (x-1) \ln x \ge 0
$$
and the last inequality is always true because the factors on the left are simultaneously negative, zero, or positive.

Equality holds exactly for $x=1$.

Comment: Thank you but I forgot to mention that it was stated to prove without taking logarithms. A weird instruction, I know!

Comment: @DhrubajyotiBhattacharjee: The *definition* of $x^x$ already involves the logarithm, so that is indeed a strange requirement. Can you update the question with the exact instructions?

Answer (score 2):

You have $y=x$ as tangent line in $x=1$ and function $x^x$ is convex.